# ns run android gives error Cannot find module '@nativescript/webpack/nativescript-target'

Tags: android, angular, webpack, nativescript

I'm trying to add nativescript to my angular project, I've been through some errors, but i can't find a solution for this one. When I run ns run it gives error  Cannot find module '@nativescript/webpack/nativescript-target' and at the end "Executing webpack failed with exit code 0." Also ns doctor android says No issues were detected, but at the end there's an X with Component @nativescript/android is not installed.
Here is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "ns run android --no-hmr",
    "ios": "ns run ios --no-hmr",
    "mobile": "ns run",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "^12.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "^12.1.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "^12.1.5",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.9.3",
    "@nativescript/android": "^8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.5",
    "@nativescript/ios": "^8.1.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.5",
    "firebaseui": "^5.0.0",
    "nativescript": "^8.1.5",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "ngx-google-analytics": "^11.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1200.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.1.5",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.3",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^11.2.0",
    "@nativescript/tslint-rules": "~0.0.5",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.42",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.1",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.23.3",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.12",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.2"
  },
  "main": "main.tns.js"
```

I found a similar github issue but it's still open:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/1156

Comment: I have the same problem now. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not